# Transform existing subdirectories inside a git repository into nested sub-git repositories

Tags: git, git-submodules

**I have only access to one (1) and only one git remote repository.**

In that git repositories I have that structure:

- root (remote git repository X)

  - A directory
  - B directory
  - C directory

Right now if I change something in A,B,C is tracked as part of the root git repository.

What I would like is to transform my current git repository as follows:

- root (remote git repository X)

  - A (remote git repository inside X)
  - B (remote git repository inside X)
  - C (remote git repository inside X)

Right now I read about submodules but it as far I've understood with submodules I will have to use different remote repositories and not my existing one.

Suggestions ?

Comment: Can you explain why you only have access to a single repository? Maybe there are alternatives.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Any solution where each directory is being “tracked” individually requires each directory to be a repository of their own. Then, you can for example use submodules to create the parent root repository that just references the three individual repositories. But unless you need to actually compose A/B/C together, there is no need for the parent repository (you can just use separate repositories instead).

So any solution really requires you to have access to new remote repositories. Otherwise, as Git always tracks the full content, every commit spans across all subdirectories.

Comment: I express my needs, why do you suggest to use multiple repositories when I explicitly stated that I can not ?

Comment: As I said, if you want the directories to work independently, then you *need* multiple repositories. Please read my answer; that’s how Git works.

Comment: Downvoting my answer will not make it less true…

Comment: Right now I've followed that http://will.willandorla.com/extract-to-git-submodule and I just need to understand how to push A,B,C in the same remote repository.

Comment: You *can’t*. Submodules are registered as remote repositories, so each submodule you want to add requires its own repository. That’s what’s going on in step 3 and 4 of your link.

Comment: That is a bad news. I'll upvote your answer. Can't I just create new repositories inside a repository ? Then I'll push root/A and I'll remember to push root as well. is that a doable, even if cumbersome, solution to my needs ?

Comment: You would have to track all the files in the `.git` folder of your inner repositories then, and that would end up in a huge mess with a lot of inefficiencies and likely also problems. You should just consider getting more remote repositories instead; repositories are super cheap, and wherever you have access to that one repository right now, you will surely be able to get more.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75211/discussion-between-boos-and-poke).

Comment: @boos Is your problem resolved now? In that case you might want to accept the answer (and remove your downvote).